# useEffect in React not update component after update store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, use-effect, react-state-management

I don't understand why React not update my object. In another component through the dispatch I update the state. In this (in code below) code in mapStateToProps categories are changing (console log show one more category). But component not rerender, although in component in useEffect I use props.categories. Event console.log in element does not run

```
const LeftSidebar = (props: any) => {
    console.log('not render after props.categories changed')
    useEffect(() => {
        props.dispatch(getCategories())
    }, [props.categories]);

    const addCategoryHandler = (categoryId: number) => {
        props.history.push('/category/create/' + categoryId)
    };

    return (
        <div className='left-sidebar'>
            <Logo/>
            <MenuSidebar categories={props.categories} onClickAddCategory={addCategoryHandler}/>
        </div>
    );
};

function mapStateToProps(state: State) {
    const categories = state.category && state.category.list;
    console.log('this categories changes, but LeftSidebar not changing')
    console.log(categories)
    return { categories };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(LeftSidebar);
```

I thought if i update state, react update components dependent on this state. How should it work? how should it work? It may be useful, the item that adds the category is not a parent or child, it is a neighbor
My reducer

```
import {CATEGORIES_GET, CATEGORY_CREATE} from "../actions/types";

export default function (state={}, action: any) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case CATEGORIES_GET:
            return {...state, list: action.payload};
        case CATEGORY_CREATE:
            return {...state, list: action.payload};
        default: return state;
    }
}
```

Thanks for solving problem. All problem was in inmutable data. I used fixtures, and not copied properly array

```
import {CATEGORIES_GET, CATEGORY_CREATE} from "./types";
import {categoryMenuItems as items} from "../../fixtureData";
import {NewCategory} from "../../types";

let categoryMenuItems = items; // My mistake, I used not immutable value. Not use fixtures for state))
let id = 33;

export function getCategories() {
    return {
        type: CATEGORIES_GET,
        payload: categoryMenuItems
    }
}

export function createCategory(newCategory: NewCategory) {
    id++
    const category = {
        title: newCategory.name,
        id: id
    };

    // MISTAKE I use same array, not cloned like let clonedCategoryMenuItems = [...categoryMenuItems]
    categoryMenuItems.push(category);

    return {
        type: CATEGORY_CREATE,
        payload: categoryMenuItems
    }
}
```

Not use fixtures for state, use real api :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe your state not is inmutable. In your reducer use spread operator to add new items

```
{
    list: [
       ...state.list,
       addedCategory
    ]
}
```

Instead of

```
state.list.push(addedCategory)
```

Comment: maybe the problem is that when I add a category, I update the list of categories, as when receiving categories

Comment: Where do you add a category to categories list?. Show that code please

Comment: useEffect make a shallow comparission of its deps, therefore if your only add a new category (via push method) to the list React interprets this as if there were no changes because the object (the list) remains the same (with more items but the same at the end of the day)

Comment: Thanks a lot. You were right. I used not immutable data. Just for test I created fixtures with category array, and not clone it. If i use cloned array, all works well. I will post action with error and with comment, may be useful for someone. Thanks for  the mention inmutable data

Comment: I have this problem when using ```useSelector, useDispatch``` from ```react-redux```