# Why isn't this React functional component failing to display an array (via .map) stored in state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm having a devil of a time getting this component to properly take an array and map out components based on it. Although I can see this array log to the console, for some reason, my component (in the dev environment) is just displaying blank. So, I know that ternary statement is going to true, but React isn't then mapping (and thus, creating JSX) based on the array.

Note: I've checked out [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59327862/useeffect-in-react-not-update-component-after-update-store) here on SO, and I haven't seen one that's quite like this. If I'm wrong, please point me in that direction!

### Expected Behavior

I am successfully setting listings to an array with 11 objects in it, so the DOM should display 11 cards using this data.

### Observed Behavior

The DOM will display `<Skeleton />`s at first, indicating that the ternary statement is flowing to the falsey code block, and then the DOM will just not display anything. White space.

### Code Sample

#### Browse (Parent)

```
    export default function Browse({ user }) {

      // prevents useEffect from infinite looping
      let [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false)
      let [listings, setListings] = useState(false) // Raw listings array pulled from DB
      let [radius, setRadius] = useState(10000)

      useEffect(() => {
        // Waits for user to come in from Auth Context
        if (typeof user.userDoc !== 'undefined' || listings.length < 1) {
          if (loaded === false) {
            let grabListings = async () => await getLocalListings().then(result => setListings(result))
            grabListings()
          }

          if (listings.length > 1) {
            setLoaded(true)
          }
        }
      }, [user, listings])

      console.log(listings) // successfully shows array in listings state

      return (
        <>
          <Navbar />
          { 
            listings
            ? listings.map(listing => {
                return (
                  <BrowseItem
                    ... // props successfully passed here
                  />
                )
              })
            : <>
                <Container style={{ marginTop: '18px' }}>
                  <Skeleton animation="wave" />
                  <Skeleton animation="wave" />
                  <Skeleton animation="wave" />
                  <Skeleton animation="wave" />
                  <Skeleton animation="wave" />
                </Container>
              </>
          }
          <Footer />
        </>
      )
    }
```

#### BrowseItem (Child)

```
    export default function BrowseItem({
      creatorProfilePic,
      creatorUsername,
      docId,
      mainImgUrl,
      productStory,
      productTitle,
      seoTitle,
      user
    }) {

      ...

      let [favorited, setFavorited] = useState(null) // whether user has favorited this item
      let [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false)

      /** Handles click of the favorite button.
      * Routes to FirebaseCalls function based on state of favorited
      */
      const handleFavorite = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        let result
        if (favorited) {
          result = await removeFavorite(docId, user.currentUid)
          if (result === 'success') {
            setFavorited(!favorited)
            setSnackMessage('Removed from Favorites')
            setOpen(true)
          } else {
            setSnackMessage('⚠️ There was an error removing this from Favorites')
            setOpen(true)
          }
        } else {
          result = await addFavorite(docId, user.currentUid)
          if (result === 'success') {
              setFavorited(!favorited)
              setSnackMessage('✓ Added to Favorites')
              setOpen(true)
            } else {
              setSnackMessage('⚠️ There was an error adding this to Favorites')
              setOpen(true)
            }
        }
      }

      useEffect(() => {
        if (!loaded) {
          // Determines whether item should default to favorited
          try {
            let userFavorites = user.userDoc.favorites
            if (userFavorites) {
              if (userFavorites.some(id => id === docId)) {
                setFavorited(true)
              }
            }
            setLoaded(true)
          } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
          }
        }
      }, [user])

      ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      ///////////////////////////// SNACKS ///////////////////////////////////
      ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      let [snackMessage, setSnackMessage] = useState('')
      let [open, setOpen] = useState(null)
      const handleSnackClose = (event, reason) => {
        if (reason === 'clickaway') {
          return
        }
        setOpen(false)
      }

      return (
        <>
          {
            loaded
            ? <>
                <Card>
                  <CardHeader
                    avatar={
                      <Avatar alt={`${creatorUsername} Profile Picture`} src={creatorProfilePic} />
                    }
                    action={
                      <IconButton>
                        <MoreHoriz />
                      </IconButton>
                    }
                    title={productTitle}
                    subheader={`${creatorUsername}`}
                  />
                  <CardMedia
                    className={classes.media}
                    image={mainImgUrl}
                    title={productTitle}
                    onClick={handleImgTouch}
                  />
                  <CardContent>
                    <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
                      {productStory}
                    </Typography>
                  </CardContent>
                  <CardActions disableSpacing>
                    <IconButton onClick={handleFavorite}>
                      {
                        favorited
                        ? <Favorite color='primary' />
                        : <Favorite />
                      }
                    </IconButton>
                    <IconButton>
                      <Share />
                    </IconButton>
                  </CardActions>
                </Card>
                <Box mb={4}></Box>
              </>
            : <>
                <Skeleton animation="wave" />
                <Skeleton animation="wave" />
                <Skeleton animation="wave" />
                <Skeleton animation="wave" />
              </>
          }
          <Snackbar
            anchorOrigin={{
              vertical: 'bottom',
              horizontal: 'left',
            }}
            open={open}
            autoHideDuration={3000}
            onClose={handleSnackClose}
            message={snackMessage}
            action={
              <>
                <Button onClick={handleFavorite} color='primary'>UNDO</Button>
                <IconButton size="small" color="inherit" onClick={handleSnackClose}>
                  <Close fontSize="small" />
                </IconButton>
              </>
            }
          />
        </>
      )
    }
```

### Stack

- "next": "^9.4.4"
- "react": "^16.8.6"
- Testing in a Next.js Development Environment

Comment: And if you console.log inside the `map` do you see it log for each entry? Similarly, if you log inside of `BrowseItem` do you see that it has mounted?

Comment: Howdy Brian. Yep, getting each listing and a console.log from inside the <BrowseItem />

Comment: That would tell us that the problem is most likely within the `BrowseItem` component, and not to do with the `map`.

Comment: A bit of (maybe) helpful context is that, if we make a minor change to this script (e.g. adding a console.log('')), which triggers the "fast refresh" of the dev environment, everything loads properly.

Comment: Interesting... okay, I'll poke around there for a bit.

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure about the problem being with the `BrowseItem`, because if I have the listings.map return a <div>hello</div> for each item in the array, still getting white space. If there was a problem with `<BrowseItem />`, I'd think that at least I'd see those little 'hello's.

Comment: But you're seeing console logs within `BrowserItem` right? If `BrowserItem` is getting triggered by the `map` to trigger the logs, but is not returning anything, then I'm not sure how the problem could be anywhere besides `BrowserItem`.. Could you add that component to the question? I might be missing something, but that's my current theory

Comment: Added. Thanks for checking this out, Brian.

Comment: *because if I have the listings.map return a <div>hello</div> for each item in the array, still getting white space* I misread this, You are right.. That wouldn't point the issue to `BrowseItem` I'm sorry

Comment: @BrianThompson new discovery. Something about this code is causing listings to get *set back* to an empty array. Basically, it will console.log(listings.length) to 11, but the *final* console.log(listings.length) is an empty array.

Comment: I've noticed the useEffect doesn't have all the state variables in the dependency array. This may cause unintended side effects.